# Sequence of subgroups of abelian group of cardinality $p^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be an abelian group of order $p^n$, where $p,n\in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$, $p$ prime. Show that there exist normal sub-groups $G_i \unlhd G$ satisfying $\{1_G\}= G_n \unlhd G_{n-1} \unlhd \dots\unlhd G_1\unlhd G_0:=G$ such that $G_{i-1}/G_i$ are cyclic of order $p$.

---

I have proven the existence of an element $g\in G$ of order $p$.

Comment: This is more or less immediate from the Fundamental Theorem of Abelian Groups, but I suspect you're looking for a more elementary method.  Please share your background and what techniques are available to you.

Comment: Hint: Define $G_{n-1} = \langle g\rangle$.  Now induct on $n,$ noting that subgroups of $G / G_{n-1}$ are in a natural correspondence with subgroups of $G$ which are supersets of $G_{n-1}.$

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks, I understand what you're writing, but I don't get how to proceed. Should I argue that there is an element $g'$ in $G/G_{n-1}$ with order $p$? What order will the subgroup in $G$ corresponding to $\langle g'\rangle$ have?

Comment: There's no reason to find some $g'.$  Since $G/G_{n-1}$ has order $p^{n-1},$ the induction hypothesis, along with the correspondence I referenced, would give $$G_{n-1}/G_{n-1} \leq G_{n-2}/G_{n-1} \leq \cdots \leq G_0/G_{n-1} = G/G_{n-1}$$ where $G_{i-1}/G_i \cong \dfrac{G_{i-1}/G_{n-1}}{G_i/G_{n-1}}$ has order $p$

Comment: @BrianMoehring What is the induction hypothesis?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your question is.  If you are wondering what an induction hypothesis is generally, you may want to [see the wikipedia page for mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Description).  If instead you are simply asking what it is in this case, remember that I said to induct on $n$.  Therefore the induction hypothesis is that the statement we are trying to prove is true when $G$ is an abelian group of order $p^{n-1}$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you, I wasn't sure what the induction hypothesis was in this case. All is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Every finite group has a [composition series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_series), see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834723/every-finite-group-has-a-composition-series). Now all you need to know is that an abelian group is simple if and only if it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_q$ for some prime $q$. Obviously $q=p$ by Lagrange's theorem.